# Generate multiple binary matrix mazes in matlab

Tags: matlab, recursion, maze

I am trying to create code generated matrixes with the following properties :

Each maze has a predefined number of boxes 
the complexity of the maze is controlled by the number of boxes [i.e. if n<=4 complx=1, n<=12 complx=2, n<=28 complx=3]. see the code for visual illustration.

```
x1 = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,3,1,1,1;1,1,2,2,2,1,1;1,3,2,2,2,3,1;1,1,2,2,2,1,1;1,1,1,3,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
x2 = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,3,2,3,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1;1,1,3,1,2,2,2,1,3,1,1;1,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,1;1,1,3,1,2,2,2,1,3,1,1;1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,3,2,3,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
x3 = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,3,2,3,1,3,2,3,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,1,1,1,1;1,1,3,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,3,1,1;1,3,2,2,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,3,1;1,1,3,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,1,3,1,1;1,1,1,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,1,1,1;1,1,3,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,1,3,1,1;1,3,2,2,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,3,1;1,1,3,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,3,1,1;1,1,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,3,2,3,1,3,2,3,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
example = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,2,3,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,2,1,1,1,1,1;1,1,3,1,1,1,3,2,2,2,1,1,3,1,1;1,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,3,1;1,1,3,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,1,3,1,1;1,1,1,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,1,1,1;1,1,3,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,1,3,1,1;1,3,2,2,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,3,1;1,1,3,1,1,1,3,2,2,2,1,1,3,1,1;1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,2,1,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,2,3,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
figure('units', 'pixels', 'position', [100 100 1200 300], 'resize', 'off'); 
subplot(1,4,1); imagesc(x1);title('complexity 1 full maze');
subplot(1,4,2); imagesc(x2);title('complexity 2 full maze');
subplot(1,4,3); imagesc(x3);title('complexity 3 full maze');
subplot(1,4,4); imagesc(example);title('complexity 3 random partial maze');
```

for n=4,n=12,n=28 the matrix is exactly as drawn below with an additional matrix of box x,y coordinates
however for n

is it possible to easily generate random variates of these mazes ?

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. What do you mean by a maze? What is the complexity of a maze? What is `n`? What are the colors on your plots?

Comment: The pattern generated is a form of a maze where the origin is the centre and end nodes are various targets. n is the number of targets. in a perfect maze of complexity 1 there are exactly 4 nodes and it is represented by the left illustration.

Comment: The numbers indicate 3 as a node, num 2 as the maze and 1 as boundary

Answer (score 0):

Well i think i solved it.

Not the most efficient way, so if anyone has improvements they are more than welcome

```
function [maze, nodes] = genMaze(tmp_maze, numOfnodes)
[x,y] = find(tmp_maze==3);
[n,dims] = size(tmp_maze);
origin = ceil(dims/2);
N = randperm(size(x,1));
D1 = bwdistgeodesic(tmp_maze>1, origin, origin,'cityblock');
maze = zeros(n,dims);
for i=1:numOfnodes
    tmpD = bwdistgeodesic(tmp_maze>1, x(N(i)), y(N(i)),'cityblock');
    D = D1 + tmpD;
    D(isnan(D)) = inf;
    path = imregionalmin(D);
    maze = maze+path;
end
subplot(1,2,1); imagesc(tmp_maze);subplot(1,2,2); imagesc(maze);
nodes = [x(N(1:numOfnodes));y(N(1:numOfnodes))];
end
```